# Select distinct including a value from a different model/table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

- I have 2 models/tables:

  ```
  class CollectionPoint < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :collection_type
  ...

  class CollectionType < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :collection_points
  ...
  ```
- Every CollectionPoint has a city (column)
- Every CollectionType has a name (column)

I would like to get all the distinct collection type names in each city in order to show a directory like this in my view:

- city A

  - collection_type.name A
  - collection_type.name B
  - collection_type.name C
  - ...
- city B

  - collection_type.name A
  - collection_type.name B
  - collection_type.name C
  - ...
- city C

  - collection_type.name A
  - collection_type.name B
  - collection_type.name C
  - ...
    ...

The best thing would be an array that is grouped by cities so that i could go like this in my view:

```
    @cities.each do |city|
       ...
       city.each do |collection_type_name|
          ...
       end
    end
```

So i tried this:

```
    CollectionPoint.select("DISTINCT city, collection_type_id")
```

But then i get only the collection type ids, not the collection type names. Also i don't need the collection point ids (which are nil in the query result anyway), so i tried this:

```
    CollectionPoint.includes(:collection_type).select("DISTINCT city, collection_types.name").references(:collection_types)
```

But this is not getting me anywhere neither.

I'm quite frustrated because i know there must be a solution to this i don't have a clue about. Maybe you could help me?

Cheers

**Solution A**

The simplest solution to this problem was adding this line of code to my controller:

```
    @cities = CollectionPoint.includes(:collection_type).select("DISTINCT city, collection_type_id").order(:city).group_by(&:city)
```

So i could show the results in my view accordingly:

```
    - @cities.each do |city, collection_points|
        %h2
            = city
        = content_tag :ul, title: "... " + city do
            %li
                = link_to "... " + city, "/.../" + city
            - collection_points.each do |cp|
                %li
                    = link_to cp.collection_type.name + " in " + city, "/" + cp.collection_type.name + "/" + city
```

**Solution B**

I guess the best solution is to create a separate City model and rework your assosiations:

```
    class City < ActiveRecord::Base
       has_many :collection_points
   has_many :collection_types, through: :collection_points
    ...
    class CollectionPoint < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :collection_type
   belongs_to :city
    ...
    class CollectionType < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :collection_points
   has_many :cities, through: :collection_points
    ...
```

Then you can do all kinds of stuff, for example finding all collection types in a specific city:

```
    City.where(name: "Cologne").first.collection_types
```

To list all distinct collection types in all distinct cities, the controller action looks like this:

```
    @cities = City.includes(:collection_types).distinct
```

And in the view you can go like:

```
    @cities.each do |city|
       city.name
       city.collection_types.each do |collection_type|
          collection_type.name
       end
    end
```

More information on this can be found here:
[Rails Model Assosiations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

Thanks for your help, guys!

Answer (score 1):

Do your CollectionName and CollectionType models have and belongs to many records? If so, this is the set up I would advise with:

**Collector.rb**

```
class Collector < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :collection_point_id, :collection_type_id
   belongs_to :collection_point
   belongs_to :collection_type
end
```

**CollectionPoint.rb**

```
class CollectionPoint < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :city
   has_many :collectors
   has_many :collection_types, :through => :collectors
end
```

**CollectionType.rb**

```
class CollectionType < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :name
   has_many :collectors
   has_many :collection_points, :through => :collectors
end
```

Then you can utilise the new ActiveRecord association and select distinct records with the group method:

```
@cities = CollectionPoint.select("DISTINCT(CITY)").all
```

Then print the @cities object with an each do method.

```
@cities.each do |city|
  ...
  city.collection_types.each do |collection_type_name|
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Maybe i'm not getting it but why would i create a third model? Am i not getting the same result with your suggestion as with @dax solution?

Comment: Well currently your model structure doesn't align with your requirements. You wish to list all the collection types in a collection point, yet a collection point belongs to a collection type and a collection type has many collection points..? Furthermore the has_many through approach builds a clearer approach and allows for listing collection points for each collection type in the future.

Comment: Updated with distinct query.

Answer (score 0):

what about using active record -

```
grouped_by_city = CollectionPoint.all.group_by { |cp| cp.city }
```

would return

```
{ :city =>{stuff in here}}
```

and then you could do this:

```
- grouped_by_city.each do |city, info|

  %p= city

    %ul
      %li= info.collection_type.name #not sure what this should be?  depends on your models
```

if you play around with that a bit I think it will work for you.  irb is your best friend!

Comment: The thing is that i would like to show only the distinct collection types (no duplicates) in each city. Also i thought of performance, isn't it faster to get only the needed results from a db query instead of fetching all collection points and filter after?

Comment: you could do this then: CollectPoint.uniq.group_by { |cp| cp.city }

Comment: This gives me unique collection points, but not collection type names within that grouped array of cities. :)